# Using Paramiko to connect a network device

Tags: python, ssh

I am using Paramiko script to connect a Cisco like device but failed. However, I can connect the device by normal ssh, here is the Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import paramiko,os
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
paramiko.common.logging.basicConfig(level=paramiko.common.DEBUG)
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('10.3.207.22',username='admin',password='')
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command("help")
print stdout.read()
ssh.close()
```

The debug information shows

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x2839510L
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 1.99, client OpenSSH_4.3)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:['aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'arcfour128', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr'] server encrypt:['aes128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'cast128-cbc', 'arcfour128', 'arcfour256', 'arcfour', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr'] client mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:['hmac-md5', 'hmac-sha1', 'hmac-ripemd160', 'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:['none', 'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Ciphers agreed: local=aes128-ctr, remote=aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:using kex diffie-hellman-group1-sha1; server key type ssh-rsa; cipher: local aes128-ctr, remote aes128-ctr; mac: local hmac-sha1, remote hmac-sha1; compression: local none, remote none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Adding ssh-rsa host key for 10.3.207.22: d2fb806d119eebe874ed2b9be3e7e7f7
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying discovered key e4ddbd54b29d935363ad027da9f28a1d in /home/chainwu/.ssh/id_rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (password) successful!
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Max packet in: 34816 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
INFO:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 1 opened.
INFO:paramiko.transport:Disconnect (code 2): Packet integrity error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "icos-ssh.py", line 12, in <module>
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command("help")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 370, in exec_command
chan.exec_command(command)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 213, in exec_command
self._wait_for_event()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1114, in _wait_for_event
raise e
paramiko.SSHException: Channel closed.
```

Here is the ssh log

```
chainwu@saturn paramico-example $ ssh -v  admin@10.3.207.22
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.3.207.22 [10.3.207.22] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/chainwu/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/chainwu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chainwu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chainwu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chainwu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chainwu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 140/256
debug2: bits set: 1006/2048
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA d2:fb:80:6d:11:9e:eb:e8:74:ed:2b:9b:e3:e7:e7:f7
debug1: Host '10.3.207.22' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/chainwu/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug2: bits set: 1006/2048
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/chainwu/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f9530e33950)
debug2: key: /home/chainwu/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/chainwu/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/chainwu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chainwu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chainwu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
admin@10.3.207.22's password:
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 10.3.207.22 ([10.3.207.22]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 131072
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0

(BCM-EVAL) >help

HELP:
Special keys:
  DEL, BS .... delete previous character
  Ctrl-A  .... go to beginning of line
  Ctrl-E  .... go to end of line
  Ctrl-F  .... go forward one character
  Ctrl-B  .... go backward one character
  Ctrl-D  .... delete current character
  Ctrl-U, X .. delete to beginning of line
  Ctrl-K  .... delete to end of line
  Ctrl-W  .... delete previous word
  Ctrl-T  .... transpose previous character
  Ctrl-P  .... go to previous line in history buffer
  Ctrl-R  .... rewrites or pastes the line
  Ctrl-N  .... go to next line in history buffer
  Ctrl-Y  .... print last deleted character
  Ctrl-Q  .... enables serial flow
  Ctrl-S  .... disables serial flow
  Ctrl-Z  .... return to root command prompt
  Tab, <SPACE> command-line completion
  Exit    .... go to next lower command prompt
  ?       .... list choices
```

I wonder how can I make Paramiko to work like ssh? Did I miss some configuration setting? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try loading the `system_host_keys`?

```
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(host, username=username, password=password, timeout=3)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(commands)
ssh_client.close()
```

Also try to make use of exceptions:

```
except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
      log.debug("Authentication problem to -- Server: %s"%host)
      output = 'Authentication Error'
except socket.error:
      log.debug("Comunication problem to -- Server: %s"%host)
      output = 'Communication Error'
```